# Определение отладочной и релизной сборки в коде приложения

Tags: android

Можно ли в коде приложения можно определить является ли данная версия отладочной или это уже релизная сборка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
}
```

Плюс есть возможность в этот файл свои данные внести, что может оказаться тем, что вам нужно на самом деле. Для этого в gradle файле пишем

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "Example"
        buildConfigField "String", "FIELD_NAME", '"Field value"'
    }
}
```